# I've got a C# Windows Forms to input values into a SQL Server database that just wont working, no errors though?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, frontend

I've created a simple Windows form to input data into a SQL Server database table. On the surface, it seems fine, no errors, but after submitting data into table, that data doesn't appear. I've looked at the where the connection is pointing and that seems fine. so I'm stuck at the moment. Any help would be great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp7
{
    public partial class Onbutton1_Click : Form
    {
        public Onbutton1_Click()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                String str = 
"den1.mssql7.gear.host;database=generic;UID=generic;password=Generic";
                String cmdText1 = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (Name) VALUES ('%'+ @Name + '%')";
                String cmdText2 = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (Age) VALUES ('%'+ @Age + '%')";

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmdText1, con);
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, con);  
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value =  textBox1.Text;
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = textBox2.Text;

                con.Open();

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get the "Complete" message shown?

Comment: "...it doesn't appear" - where does it not appear? In the database or in your program? I see you create a new `DataSet` but you do not use it. Did you mean to use it to update the UI?

Comment: The program seems fine, I get the message box. Just nothing in the Db. The Dataset was left over from an earlier idea but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: If you get the message then you are getting an exception and your program is not fine. Look at the exception details instead of throwing them away.

Comment: I'd of said its pointing at the wrong database or a problem somewhere around there but thinking this I've checked it multiple times and it is correct.

Comment: Instead of showing "Complete", show es.Message. You must understand that exception messages are very helpful. You will get nowhere claiming your program is fine yet doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here

```
String cmdText1 = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (Name) VALUES ('%'+ @Name + '%')";
String cmdText2 = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (Age) VALUES ('%'+ @Age + '%')";
```

This needs to be

```
 String cmdText1 = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (Name) VALUES (@Name)";
 String cmdText2 = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (Age) VALUES (@Age)";
```

Btw, curious why this is two separate statements. If you want to insert Name and Age to a single row, it needs to be a single query.

```
 String cmdText = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (Name,Age) VALUES (@Name,@Age)";
 cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = textBox1.Text;
 cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = textBox2.Text;
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP did not in fact want to store `'%'+ @Name + '%'` in the table?

Comment: @GSerg very well, that is a possibility. Sorry didn't think about it. Also wanted to point out the two Insert statements for Age and Name. Thinking now, there is a possibility it could be intentional as well

Comment: Wondering whether I should remove the answer or wait for Joe to verify his intensions

Comment: I have implemented your changes @AnuViswan and changed from the two separate statements to a string query but still no input. Gotta say I'm lost.

Comment: "still no input" ? do you mean there is no entry in Db yet ?

Comment: That is correct. all seems to go okay, no errors but just not inputting the values.

Comment: As has since been discovered, the actual problem OP had was related to a malformed connection string. But this suggestion is very likely to be appropriate - fields within a window generally relate to a single "thing" which should be stored as a single row. One can easily assume that "name" and "age" are associated with a single person.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Crowcoder for the prompt the exception indicated a keyword error. Just wanted a little more than I had given it.

```
String str ="server=den1.mssql7.gear.host;
database=generic;
UID=generic;
password=Generic";
```